# How do I setup a form to handle multiple models?

Tags: cakephp

How do I setup a form to handle multiple models? Do I need to send multiple models to the form? This would be to save for example the order items on an order form as well as the order form basic details..

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Forms-that-add-edit-multiple-models-td1278974.html

Comment: Add a bit more information to your question... If you want multiple model in a form, normally you use `Model.fieldname` as `fieldname` in your `input` instead of only `fieldname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of form for two models:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Book');      //your main model is Book
echo $this->Form->input('title');      //'title' field for Book
echo $this->Form->input('Author.name') //related model Author with a field 'name'
```

In your $this->request->data you will have the following:

```
array(
    'Book' => array(
            'title' => '...'
        ),
    'Author' => array(
            'name' => '...'
        )
    )
```

And to save it simply run this into your controller:

```
$this->Book->saveAll($this->request->data)
```